# How to calculate number of time names repeated in dictionary in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
l1 = [{"ID": 1, "Name": "Sagar", "Email": "Sagar@gmail.com", "Designation": "Software Developer"},
      {"ID": 3, "Name": "John", "Email": "dohn@gmail.com", "Designation": "Software Tester"},
      {"ID": 1, "Name": "Sagar", "Email": "Sagar@gmail.com", "Designation": "Software Developer"},
      {"ID": 1, "Name": "Sagar", "Email": "Sagar@gmail.com", "Designation": "Software Developer"},
      {"ID": 2, "Name": "Devid", "Email": "devid@gmail.com", "Designation": "Data Analyst"},
      {"ID": 3, "Name": "john", "Email": "john@gmail.com", "Designation": "Software Tester"},
      {"ID": 5, "Name": "Sandy", "Email": "Sandy@gmail.com", "Designation": "Software Developer"},
      {"ID": 4, "Name": "Jenifer", "Email": "Jenifer@gmail.com", "Designation": "Software Developer"}]

l2 = [{"ID": 1, "Name": "Sagar", "Email": "Sagar@gmail.com", "Designation": "Software Developer"},
      {"ID": 3, "Name": "John", "Email": "dohn@gmail.com", "Designation": "Software Tester"},
      {"ID": 1, "Name": "Sagar", "Email": "Sagar@gmail.com", "Designation": "Software Developer"},
      {"ID": 1, "Name": "Sagar", "Email": "Sagar@gmail.com", "Designation": "Software Developer"},
      {"ID": 2, "Name": "Devid", "Email": "devid@gmail.com", "Designation": "Data Analyst"},
      {"ID": 3, "Name": "john", "Email": "john@gmail.com", "Designation": "Software Tester"},
      {"ID": 5, "Name": "Sandy", "Email": "Sandy@gmail.com", "Designation": "Software Developer"},
      {"ID": 4, "Name": "Jenifer", "Email": "Jenifer@gmail.com", "Designation": "Software Developer"}]
```

I want result as number of time Name Sagar repeated in this dictionaries. Is any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in one line using comprehension passed to `collections.Counter`:

```
import collections

print(collections.Counter(x['Name'] for x in l1)["Sagar"])
```

this creates a counter dict with the names of all dicts of your list, then takes the count for the particular name `Sagar`

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code:

```
print sum(1 for element in l1 if element['Name'] == 'Sagar' )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use another dictionary and loop through the list.

```
names = {}
for person in l:
    name = person["Name"]
    if name in names:
        names[name] += 1
    else:
        names[name] = 1
```

Comment: it's a very unpythonic solution.

Comment: Sure, it's easy to understand though